# How to find the index array of a array of elements?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to use an example to show what I want.

```
A = [5 1 2 4 3]; % of distinct values

B = [3 3 1 5 2];
```

Can I find a library function implemented in MATLAB such that:

```
C = [5 5 2 3 1] = someFun(A, B)
```

i.e. `C(i) = find(A == B(i))`

Note that I am asking for a library function, as in that case it is highly optimized. If you are sure there doesn't exist such a function, that is also an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of solutions:

#### for-loop

```
C = zeros(size(B));
for i=1:numel(B)
    C(i) = find(A == B(i));
end
```

#### arrayfun

```
C = arrayfun(@(n)find(A==n), B)
```

#### vectorized equality using BSXFUN

```
[C,~] = find( bsxfun(@eq, B, A.') )
```

#### ismember

```
[~,C] = ismember(B,A)
```

Comment: personally I would go with [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html)

Comment: +1 but watch out that `'`. It won't work if `A` is complex. It should be `.'`

Comment: right, we don't want the complex conjugates.. I'd also be careful if the number are floating-points not just integers, and instead check that the absolute difference is less than some epsilon threshold

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
IX(A) = [1:length(A)];
C=IX(B)
```

This is 10 times faster than the `ismember` solution:

```
A=randperm(1e5);
B=ceil(rand(1,1e4)*length(A));

tic; 
[D,C1]=ismember(B,A); 
toc % Elapsed time is 0.013728 seconds.


tic
IX(A) = [1:length(A)];
C=IX(B);
toc % Elapsed time is 0.001506 seconds.
```

But this can be used under stricter conditions:

1. `A` contains only unique integers.
2. 0 < `B(i)` < `max(A)` for all `i`
3. The memory can hold an array of size `max(A)`

Comment: A very nice answer. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question a little bit?

If you want a function that returns the index of A that contains the value B(i) then a function like this should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
{
    for(int q = 0; q < A.length; q++)
    {
        if(B[i] == A[q])
           C[i] = q;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Plz see my revised question.